# Auth0 lock blocked on Safari IOS 12 because of third party cookies

Tags: c#, ios, authentication, safari, auth0

I'm using a c# Web API on the backend and auth0 Universal login lock to authenticate my users. Everytime a user tries to log in using safari 12 it won't stop redirecting him to the home page because Apple is now blocking third party cookies on their browsers, It only works if the user disables that protection manually. Is there anyway of solving that problem without using custom domains in Auth0?

Link to issue reported on github:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4647

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, Safari introduced Intelligent Tracking Prevention (ITP) which disabled third-party cookies. The best way to make sure cross-origin authentication requests are not blocked by certain browsers is to use Auth0's [custom domains](https://auth0.com/docs/custom-domains) feature.

Comment: Is this the only solution? I'm currently facing this issue and I cannot justify $20 a month for this simple little issue (custom domains are only able to be used on the paid Auth0 subscriiption) ? I'm just a learning developer..